# pdflatex.exe failed to compile an input file with BOM (Byte Order Mark)

Tags: unicode, cjk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX baffled by BOM---Unicode's byte order mark.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10474/latex-baffled-by-bom-unicodes-byte-order-mark)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage{pinyin}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{cyberbit}

Test

新年快乐

\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [latex-baffled-by-bom-unicodes-byte-order-mark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10474/latex-baffled-by-bom-unicodes-byte-order-mark)