# Weird error in file converted from docx to txt by LibreOffice

Tags: debugging, msword, open-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX baffled by BOM---Unicode's byte order mark.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10474/latex-baffled-by-bom-unicodes-byte-order-mark)

I have a large text file in `.docx` format, and I used LibreOffice to convert it to plain text so I could nicely format it with LaTeX.

I've fixed as many of the problems as I could find (unescaped %s, etc), but there's one persistent bug in the document that still remains.

When I run LaTeX, I get as an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
...
l.1 
     ��%\documentclass{article}
```

My preamble consists of

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
```

so I'm definitely not just missing a `\begin{document}`.

I suspect the `��%` means that LibreOffice put a few unicode characters at the beginning of the file (I don't know what the � is, it just shows up as a question mark on my computer), and that this is causing LaTeX to fail somehow.

**If these characters are the problem, how do I remove them?**

**If these characters aren't the problem, what else could it be?**

Comment: These bytes are called [Byte-Order-Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). See e.g. [How do I remove the BOM character from my xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295472/how-do-i-remove-the-bom-character-from-my-xml-file) on how to remove it.

Comment: See also [LaTeX baffled by BOM---Unicode's byte order mark.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10474/latex-baffled-by-bom-unicodes-byte-order-mark)