# Strange behaviour after adding a chapter

Tags: chapters

My problem is that after adding a chapter now I have a blank page with just these characters:

```
ï¾
```

The page is between the new chapter and appendix A.

I'm wondering why. How ca I get rid of that page?

Here's part of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,singleside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{ia_urb_thesis}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}


\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{upquote}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\usepackage{marvosym}

\usepackage{listings}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname ttfamily \endcsname
{\selectfont}{\small}{}{}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

\usepackage{float}

\lstset{literate={@}{\MVAt}1}

\patchcmd{\verb}{\dospecials}{\dospecials\atspecial}{}{}
\def\atspecial{\begingroup\lccode`~=`@
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\MVAt
  \catcode`@=\active}
```

Comment: Please provide a fully compilable Minimal Working Example (ending with `\end{document}`). Also don't tag all your questions with `latex-project`.

Comment: My guess is that the new file is saved in UTF-8 with BOM (byte order mark) that causes the trouble at the begin of the file. Try to save the file without BOM.

Comment: You probably have `\input{file}` and `file.tex` has a Byte Order Mark at the beginning. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10474/latex-baffled-by-bom-unicodes-byte-order-mark

Comment: How do I do that? ..sorry can you please tell me exactly what i should do?

Comment: Whenever I have to add a new chapter i create a .txt file then I rename the file with extension .tex...is that the problem?..thanks

Comment: I've had such problems too... Check that after the `\include` of the chapter there isn't any garbage, check that the offending chapter doesn't start in junk (a popular place in which gremlins hide is in comments before the `\chapter`, just before the `\chapter`, ...). Maybe your Windows adds some garbage to mark the file as UTF-8 at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem, which got solved by removing BOM. I used `tail --bytes=+4 text.txt` as described by http://www.linuxask.com/questions/how-to-remove-bom-from-utf-8