# Alternative to Morewrites

Tags: write

Is there an alternative to `morewrites`?

Using the `glossaries` package for different types of lists, as well as `lstlisting` package has put me over the maximum writes number, however, I cannot seem to load `morewrites` as it is throwing many "invalid utf-8 sequence" errors, and I have no idea where to begin tracing the culprit.

Sorry this question is "vague".

EDIT: I have been able to pinpoint a (there may be more) potential conflict, here is a NMWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%Seems to be originating from font selection, ie, helvet package.
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**The above throws the following errors:**

1. `String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence \begin{document}`
2. `String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence \begin{document}`
3. `String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence .../04 scalable font definitions

   for OT1/phv.]`
4. String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence .../04 scalable font
   definitions for OT1/phv.]

Comment out the `helvet` package, and the document compiles.

Comment: I am able to compile the MWE without error under both `xelatex` and `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Werner, What about Lualatex? I was actually about to clarify this in my question as you posted.

Comment: @ADP 'Works for me' with TeX Live 2013 pdfLaTeX/XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Then WTF is going on with my system. Probably because running on Ubuntu.

Comment: @ADP MWE works without any errors for me also on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS TeXLive 2013 pdflatex

Comment: I am running the same system. Damn it.

Comment: @ADP may be it's byte order mark (BOM). [LaTeX baffled by BOM---Unicode's byte order mark](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10474/15717). I suggest take care of encoding properly(editor and inputenc should match) and copy the code from current file and create a new UTF-8 file and paste it to verify the run

Comment: @ADP Could you add `\listfiles` and edit in the file list you get: might illuminate a bit

Comment: I re-installed texlive 2013, and, the problem has gone away, which is excellent.

Comment: the last resort is to re-install TL. To find where the bug was and resolve it would be good idea to help future visitors, To make it answered could you make some  answer what might be the possible causes of errors. If it's _only_ error pertaining to your previous installation, close the Q on hand

Comment: You would have to be joking. I have no idea, in amongst something like 1.5GB of texlive files, what the source of the problem was....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem solved with a software update