# Blank Page and "Missing \begin{document}" error in simple document

Tags: miktex, texniccenter

Im new with LaTeX, I have MikTek and TeXnic Center. The first time I tried to write a document I noticed I couldn't cancel terms in mathematical equations, so iI download the `cancel` package and installed it by hand.

Now the new package is working (or at least that is what I think), but for example the following simple document generates a `Missing \begin{document}` error and a first blank page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}

\title{...}
\author{...}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{equation}
\cancel{a}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I cant copy all the build output from the TexnicCenter output window, but here you can see some part of it [image]

Why is this?

Comment: This is referred to as a [Byte-Order-Mark (or BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), and therefore the problem is similar to [LaTeX baffled by BOM---Unicode's byte order mark](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10474/5764).

Comment: Are you using TeXnicCenter 2? you should save the file using a UTF-8 encoding (check the bottom-right of the editor window).

Comment: @Werner Thanks!. The encoding was the problem.