# Unexpected error with report class

Tags: graphics, titles, mactex, report

Anyone who knows why it gives me the error `Undefined control sequence.`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\title{
    {Title}\\
    {\large MyUniversity}\\
    {\includegraphics{image.jpg}}
}
\author{Author Name}
\date{7 Jenuary 2015}   

\begin{document}

\maketitle



\end{document}
```

Comment: Which command does it suggest as being undefined?

Comment: l.3 \@@wrindexm@m this one I have absolutely no idea of what does it mean

Comment: @chabert That's an internal command of the memoir class. Remove the `.aux` file and retry.

Comment: @egreg I have tried and now it says Package inputting Error: Unicode char \u8:àdi not set up for use with LaTeX

Comment: @chabert: Since you're not loading any funny characters, this may be related to [LaTeX baffled by BOM---Unicode's byte order mark.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10474/5764) Copy-and-paste your entire code into a clean non-unicode editor and then save it. Then open it up again and recompile.

Comment: I worked out by uninstalling and installing back the whole MacTeX package from my mac and now everything work fine! thanks by the way

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by reinstalling the software, according to the OP

Answer (score 0):

I try your code with pdflatex, there is no error. 
Maybe there is one of the packages which is not yet installed in your TEX distribution.
If you are using the MikTEX distribution in window OS, then you can check the proper installation by running MikTEX\miktex\bin\mo_admin.exe

Comment: I am using MacTeX actually and editing with TeXShop