# Compiling tex file using pdflatex and cmd - strange behavior

Tags: macros, pdftex, miktex, windows, filesystem-access

I'm have a really strange problem here. I have a tex file which I compile to a pdf file using the pdflatex.exe which comes with MikTeX. The Problem is now that it seems a problem when the tex-file which I want compile isn't stored in the "C:/Users/Username"-directory of the user. When I save the tex file to C:/Users/Username/Desktop for example  and then compile the file calling pdflatex.exe from the cmd everything is fine.
But when I save the file to some other directory (D:/tex/ for example) and then compile the file with the same arguments for the pdflatex.exe I get the following error: ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

The pdf is created and it looks good only the blank page at the begin is strange and shouldn't be there.
It seems that the folder where the document is saved is a problem in the second case!?
Running cmd as Administrator doesn't solve the problem :-/

That is how I calling the pdflatex from the cmd:

```
pdflatex.exe -shell-escape -file-line-error test.tex
```

Here my example test.tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**
When I now compile the example file it doesn't work for both file locations!!!

Here is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.1.29)  16 FEB 2015 16:57
entering extended mode
**minbsp.tex
(C:\Users\username\Desktop\minbsp.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 ï
     »¿\documentclass{article}
? 
Missing character: There is no ï in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no » in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ¿ in font nullfont!
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84

Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--284
[]
 []

\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
[1{C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}])
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\ngermanb.ldf"
Language: ngermanb 2008/07/06 v2.6n new German support from the babel system

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2008/07/08 v3.8m Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)
\l@naustrian = a dialect from \language\l@ngerman 
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 92.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
File: utf8.def 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu"
File: t1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
   defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
   defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
   defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
   defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
   defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
   defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
   defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
   defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
   defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
   defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
   defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
   defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
   defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
   defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
   defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
   defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
   defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
   defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
   defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
   defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
   defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
   defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
   defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
   defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
   defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
   defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
   defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
   defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
   defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
   defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
   defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
   defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
   defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
   defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
   defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
   defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
   defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
   defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
   defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
   defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
   defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
   defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
   defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
   defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
   defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
   defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)
   defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)
   defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)
   defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)
   defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)
   defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)
   defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)
   defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)
   defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)
   defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)
   defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)
   defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)
   defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)
   defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)
   defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)
   defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)
   defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)
   defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)
   defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)
   defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)
   defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)
   defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)
   defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)
   defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)
   defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)
   defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)
   defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)
   defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)
   defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)
   defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)
   defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)
   defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)
   defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)
   defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)
   defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)
   defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)
   defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)
   defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)
   defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
   defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
   defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)
   defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)
   defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)
   defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)
   defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)
   defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)
   defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)
   defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)
   defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
   defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)
   defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)
   defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)
   defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)
   defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
   defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
   defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu"
File: ot1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu"
File: omsenc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
(C:\Users\username\Desktop\minbsp.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
 [2

] (C:\Users\username\Desktop\minbsp.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 763 strings out of 493921
 8430 string characters out of 3147288
 58355 words of memory out of 3000000
 4113 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 24i,4n,24p,189b,119s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/p
ublic/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on minbsp.pdf (2 pages, 13003 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: `test.tex` is a very common name. Are you sure that you are compiling *your* test.tex and not some other found e.g. in the texmf tree? Are you in the directory of your file when you start pdflatex?

Comment: There is an unicode BOM at the begin of the document http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10474/latex-baffled-by-bom-unicodes-byte-order-mark

Comment: Updated the question! But now it isn't working anymore for the file in C:/Users/username/Desktop...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that was the problem. How do you recognized that the BOM is the problem? I can't see any error message regarding the BOM problem. Only the three lines in the log file which look like "Missing character: There is no xx in font nullfont" seem to give a hint on that problem!? Very poor that there is no meaningful error message in the log :-(

Comment: The error message is very meaningful: below the error itself it tells you that the problem is in line one before \documentclass and shows the problemic input. You only need to find out or know which utf8 input shows up like this in an 8bit application like pdftex