# How to remove i£ij at the bottom left corner under my abstract

Tags: pdftex, texworks

I have an `i£ij` at the bottom left corner under my abstract. I don't know why. How do I get rid of it? Using TeXworks. Actually there is an umlaut over the first `i`.

I use pdfLaTeX to compile.

Here is a MWEB:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}  % To make section headings italicized
\usepackage{abstract}

\title{Title}
\author{}
                                        
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: TeXworks is just a front-end. Which TeX distribution do you use? Which TeX engine -- pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX -- do you employ? Which document class do you employ? Please post a minimum working example (MWE) that generates the problem behavior you wish to suppress.

Comment: most likely you have a BOM character in a file that you are inputting, you should try to delete it. But hard to say if you show no code. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10474/latex-baffled-by-bom-unicodes-byte-order-mark

Comment: @Mico - I added a MWEB. It seems to be related to the lmodern package. When I remove that it goes away. I'm using lmodern to italicize the subsection headings.

Comment: I deleted the lmodern package and I don't seem to need it anymore to italicize. I had updated my whole Tex package a week ago so maybe my new version doesn't need lmodern to italicize subsection headings. I think I'm good now.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the lmodern package, the i£ij went away, and I don't seem to need lmodern anymore to italicize subsections. I had updated my whole Tex package a week ago so maybe my new version doesn't need lmodern to italicize subsection headings. I think I'm good now. I guess the moral of the story is, always to a MWEB before posting a question on the stackexchange.

Comment: +1 for "I guess the moral of the story is, always to a MWEB before posting a question on the stackexchange." :-)