# Undefined control sequence \documentclass on arXiv

Tags: pdftex, arxiv

arXiv continually throws this error whenever I upload a document:

```
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./cabbage.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
{IEEEtran}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
{IEEEtran}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on cabbage.log.
```

I have tried several recommendations e.g. starting a new file ([from a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540681/error-when-getting-ieee-paper-into-arxive))but the error hasn't gone away.
It seems TexLive uses `pdftex`, which also fails on my computer. However `pdfLatex` works, therefore I am wondering if there is a solution.

Comment: arxiv normally uses pdflatex, you seem to have forced it to use plain tex somehow, I had a quick look at their submission, they accept plain tex but I couldn't see how you could configure that, probably a more fluent arxiv user will pass by and be able to help...

Comment: Old question but maybe still worth a comment: the arXiv compiler doesn't like magic comments like `% !TeX program = ...` at all. For reasons I never understood they lead to this error.

Comment: @campa: the sequence `%!` is how postscript files begin, and arXiv's system that guesses at what files are based on how the file is written gets confused.

Answer (score 1):

You're very likely misreading arXiv's default for how the AutoTeX log processes (at the time of this reply, it's `hlatex, latex, hpdflatex, pdflatex, htex, tex`, and then it fails if none were successful). The log is then displayed at the process step in that order (unless you've disabled hyperref).

There isn't enough info here to really debug what you've done, so you should direct your question to help@arxiv.org, since this is specific to our tex engine and not latex in general.